# Reference type and GetValue()

Tags: javascript

Why if we run the following javascript code:

```
        var foo = {
           bar: function () {
               alert('s');
           }
       }

      //1. foo.bar();
      //2. var a = foo.bar;
      //3. var b = (foo.bar);          
       (foo.bar)();
```

we'll get an error message "foo is undefined", but if we uncomment 1. or 2. or 3. line we'll get alert 's'? I know that it's about Reference type and GetValue(), but I don't really understand the point.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you don't have a semicolon before the `(foo.bar)`.

This causes the `(...)` to be interpreted as a function call operator, so it's trying to invoke the previous expression as though it was a function.

```
  var foo = {
       bar: function () {
           alert('s');
       }
   }(foo.bar) // <-- It sees it like this
```

If you terminate the previous with a `;`, it'll work.

```
   var foo = {
       bar: function () {
           alert('s');
       }
   }; // <--- right here

  //1. foo.bar();
  //2. var a = foo.bar;
  //3. var b = (foo.bar);          
   (foo.bar)();
```

So the reason it worked when the other lines were uncommented is that they are terminated.

If you want to exclude semicolons *(which is what I do)*, you'll generally be safe if you follow these rules:

- Never begin a new line with a `(` unless you have a `;` before it
- Never begin a new line with a `[` unless you have a `;` before it

Whenever I start a line with one of those characters, I put a `;` *before* it so I know the previous statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 3):

You need a `;` after the definition of `foo`.

Your code is parsed as `var foo = { ... }(foo.bar)`.

This is interpreted as defining an object, calling it as a function (which would have given a different error had it gotten up to that point), then calling the return value of that function as another function.

The error you get is that `foo` doesn't exist inside its definition.